# Javascript changing if statement inside .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say for example I have a checkbox with an html id="delete". I wanted the database to then have a boolean/bit value of 1 if it is deleted and 0 if it is not deleted.
I got the deleted to work with the statement, but it wont change the value back to 0

```
if($("#delete").checked = true){
    $("#delete").val() == 1;
}else if($("#delete").checked = false)){
    $("#delete").val() == 0;
}
```

The statement works and marks as deleted but it does not undelete.So I figured a change statement would work so I tried a .change function but still no luck

```
$("#delete").change(function () {
    if (($("#delete").checked = false)) {
        alert("a");
        $("#delete").val() == 0;
    }
});
```

the alert never gets hit

Comment: To set the `value`, it's `$("delete").val(0);`

Comment: You have `==` and `=` the wrong way around for a start. `=` for assignment, `==` or `===` for comparison

Comment: Read jQuery's val() documentation on how to properly use it. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: to set `val()` in Jquery you need to to this `$("#delete").val('0');`

Comment: A checkbox has its own natural boolean state, !checked|checked. You appear to be trying to engineer another state to mirror that natural state. Why?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#delete").val($("#delete").is(':checked') ? '1' : '0');
```

Exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/ju9dchow/

Comment: `$("#delete").checked` will be `undefined` always because jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property.

Comment: A jQuery object is not a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

i'll just correct your syntaxe because it's not valid

```
 if($("#delete").checked == true){
           //                ^------------ add one more equal =
        $("#delete").val('1');
    }else if($("#delete").checked == false)){
        $("#delete").val('0');
    }
```

and you better use this

```js
$("#delete").change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    $(this).val(1)
  }else{
    $(this).val(0)
  }
  alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="delete" />
```

Comment: also if (($("#delete").checked == false)) {

Comment: And it should be `$("#delete").prop("checked")`

Comment: you dont need to set a value for a checkbox by default will be false if not selected or true if selected

Comment: @Pointy or `$('#delete').is(':checked')`

Comment: @putvande `$("#delete").checked` is very popular however.